# API calls required to obtain buyer's e-mail

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, bigcommerce

I'm using PayPal Express checkout with BigCommerce with a sandbox account. Via the BigCommerce API, only one field is supplied, which is also listed via the http://www.sandbox.paypal.com interface as the "Unique Transaction ID" under "Details":

```
<payment_provider_id>0P192574JB861364C</payment_provider_id>
```

The orders are going from BigCommerce into an ERP system that, for PayPal Express orders, expects the PayPal username (e-mail) to be provided.

Via the PayPal REST API (or otherwise), is there a way derive the e-mail used during the transaction via the transaction ID?

If so, which API call(s) would be necessary to get the e-mail?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the REST API cannot do this but the Classic API can. I will test https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/

Answer (score 0):

The GetTransactionDetails of the classic NVP/SOAP APIs will let you get the buyer's e-mail with only a transaction ID.

Info is here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/